# Warning: mongodb.service changed on disk. Run systemctl daemon-reload to reload

Tags: ubuntu

I'm installing [Modern Honey Network](https://threatstream.github.io/mhn/) but every time I get to the command `sudo ./install.sh` I end up with this error

```
Warning: mongodb.service changed on disk. Run systemctl daemon-reload to reload
```

and I don't know how to get past that, any help would be appreciated.

I'm supposed to get a configuration page after the installation but I can't get there because of this error.

Comment: That's not an error.  It's a warning, hence the word `Warning`.  The installation script proceeds to tell you all sorts of interesting stuff immediately after that.  Since you have not told the world _the actual error_, and the world is not telepathic, the world cannot help you.

Answer (score 3):

The warning `Warning: mongodb.service changed on disk. Run systemctl daemon-reload to reload` tells you that the configuration presently written to /etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service is not the configuration that the system uses at this moment. Issuing `systemctl daemon-reload` will make sure, in the words of systemctl's man page, that the contents of backing files on disk match the system manager's understanding of these units.

If this is the root cause of you not getting that configuration page I cannot tell. It's possible, depending on the difference of the old and the new configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Just run `systemctl daemon-reload` as requested in the message?

Comment: I did try that, several times but I still get the same error

Comment: Every time you run the `install.sh`script, the .service file is probably modified, that explains why you see that. If everything else is working, ignore that message?

Comment: I'm supposed to get a configuration page after the installation but I can't get there because of this error

Comment: Are you sure it's due to this? Is mongodb started, what's the output of `systemd status mongodb.service`? You should update your question and add more information, it's not possible to help you only with this.

Comment: [It does indeed overwrite it every time.](https://github.com/threatstream/mhn/blob/master/scripts/install_mongo.sh#L15)

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the system or in my case AWS ec2 instance solved this.